# Groovy code to check weather particular branch is already present on remote machine?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to deploy code on remote machine using jenkins and groovy pipeline. But when we are always overriding the existing repository without checking the version of the repository.

**scenario 1:** Jenkins trigger pipeline Job on Fresh machine:

1. Checkout repo,
2. Build the code
3. Install client

**scenario 2:** Same slave machine used above :

1. Code present on Machine (same code) as there is no change in GIT repo.
2. Skip checkout if same version of repository is already present.

How to check whether same version is available on machine if yes skip checkout go for next step

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear. Are you trying to checkout a repo everytime, but you want to check if directory exists or not before clone/checkout on a machine not running jenkins? You might have to use ansible to do that

Comment: scenario 1: Jenkins trigger pipeline Job on Fresh machine: 1. Checkout repo, 2. Build the code 3. Install client                                                                                                                                scenario 2: Same slave machine used above : 1. Code present on Machine (same code) as there is no change in GIT repo. so checkout can be skipped in case off same version of repository .. How to check whether same version is available on machine if yes skip checkout go for next step.. Thanks @MoZiauddin

Comment: Do you Checkout the repo into the workspace or a sub directory with name of the repo.

Comment: @MoZiauddin entire repo in workspace not Sub directory